# appLicensingVerdict returns LICENSED in which cases?

Tags: android, google-play-integrity-api

I'm implementing the Play Integrity API.

In the integrity response there is `appLicensingVerdict`, [documented](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#account-details-field) as:

appLicensingVerdict can have the following values:

```
LICENSED
    The user has an app entitlement.
    In other words, the user installed or bought your app on Google Play.
UNLICENSED
    [...]
UNEVALUATED
    [...]
```

How does it more precisely work?

I noticed that if I run the App from Android Studio, the integrity check returns LICENSED.

Maybe because on my device I previously installed the App from Play Store?

I need to know exactly when it returns every value, otherwise how I can implement it in the correct way in order to not exclude genuine users?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked out the following section in the android [dev docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#account-details-field)? There is an explanation to what each state means and when it is returned.

Comment: @FabioNettis sure, but as I pointed out in the question, why does the install from Android Studio returns LICENSED? The docs about UNEVALUATED also say few info.

Comment: I'd say because it is a simulator and you've installed it directly through android studio. Try side loading the apk onto your simulator and try again, to my understanding you should receive `UNLICENSED`.  Furthermore `UNEVALUATED ` means application integrity was not evaluated since a necessary requirement was missed. For example DeviceIntegrity did not meet the minimum bar.

Comment: We're talking about our understanding, bu is there any list of cases which trigger a specific integrity result?